# GUI not loading but seems to be running

Tags: java, swing

## Problem

When I am starting the `PetUI` main class from the `actionPerformed` function in my `StartGUI` class, the `PetUI` dialog does not start with anything on the screen but it seems to be running in the background. For debugging purposes, the pet will die within a few seconds. Once the pet dies, the screen updates and you can see the correct screen until you press OK and it will load the `StartGUI` class again so you can make a new pet and start over.

#### Note

When I run the `PetUI` main directly from the IDE, it loads correctly and follows out all functions without error.

## Images:

#### When starting from `StartGUI` class:

[image: starting from StartGUI class]

The dialog on the left is the `StartGUI` class, and then one on the right is the PetUI class started from the `StartGUI` class.

#### After Pet Death:

[image: after pet death]

Now that the pet is dead, you can simply see that the `PetUI` class has updated its dialog, and you can see what is correctly supposed to be shown.

#### Running `PetUI` directly from IDE (IntelliJ Idea)

[image]

Now you can see that it works and does it's function correctly.

## Code

### `PetUI` Class:

```
package vps.main.gui;

import vps.main.Pet;
import vps.util.io;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/**
 * Created by XXXX on 3/23/2016.
 */
public class PetUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public static Pet mainPet = new Pet("Unknown Pet", 100, 100, 100, 100);
    static JProgressBar healthBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
    static JProgressBar hungerBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
    static JProgressBar happinessBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
    static JLabel foodCount = new JLabel();
    static JLabel medpackCount = new JLabel();
    static int medpacks = 10;
    static int food = 25;
    static JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JLabel petInfo = new JLabel("Name:" + mainPet.getName() + " | Age: "+mainPet.getAge());
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem save = new JMenu("Save");
    JButton healButton = new JButton("", new ImageIcon("src\\vps\\files\\ambulanceIcon.png"));
    JButton feedButton = new JButton("", new ImageIcon("src\\vps\\files\\feedIcon.png"));
    JButton playButton = new JButton("", new ImageIcon("src\\vps\\files\\playIcon.png"));
    JButton quitButton = new JButton("", new ImageIcon("src\\vps\\files\\quitIcon.png"));
    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
    JPanel bars = new JPanel();

    public PetUI() {
        super("Pet UI");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        buttons.add(healButton);
        buttons.add(feedButton);
        buttons.add(playButton);
        buttons.add(quitButton);
        bars.add(healthBar);
        bars.add(hungerBar);
        bars.add(happinessBar);
        happinessBar.setStringPainted(true);
        hungerBar.setStringPainted(true);
        healthBar.setStringPainted(true);
        happinessBar.setString("Happiness");
        hungerBar.setString("Hunger");
        healthBar.setString("Health");
        healButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        healButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        healButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        feedButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        feedButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        feedButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        playButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        playButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        playButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        quitButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        quitButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        quitButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        playButton.addActionListener(this);
        healButton.addActionListener(this);
        feedButton.addActionListener(this);
        quitButton.addActionListener(this);
        save.addActionListener(this);
        add(petInfo);
        add(medpackCount);
        add(buttons);
        add(foodCount);
        add(bars);
        menuBar.add(file);
        file.add(save);


    }

    public static int getMedpacks() {
        return medpacks;
    }

    public static void setMedpacks(int medpacks) {
        PetUI.medpacks = medpacks;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PetUI p = new PetUI();
        p.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        p.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p.setSize(640, 480);
        p.setVisible(true);
        while (true) {
            happinessBar.setValue((int) Math.round(mainPet.getHappiness()));
            healthBar.setValue((int) Math.round(mainPet.getHealth()));
            hungerBar.setValue((int) Math.round(mainPet.getHunger()));
            mainPet.setHappiness(mainPet.getHappiness() - 0.1);
            mainPet.setHunger(mainPet.getHunger() - 0.5);
            //color set
            /**
             * if val greater than 75 = great
             * if val less than 75 = good
             * if val less than 50 = OK
             * if val less than 25 = bad
             * if val less than or equ 0 = dead/horrible
             */

            if (mainPet.getHappiness() > 75) {
                happinessBar.setString("Ecstatic");
                happinessBar.setForeground(Color.green);
            }
            if (mainPet.getHappiness() <= 75) {
                happinessBar.setString("Happy");
                happinessBar.setForeground(Color.magenta);
            }
            if (mainPet.getHappiness() <= 50) {
                happinessBar.setString("OK");
                happinessBar.setForeground(Color.orange);
            }
            if (mainPet.getHappiness() <= 25) {
                happinessBar.setString("Sad");
                happinessBar.setForeground(Color.red);
            }
            if (mainPet.getHappiness() <= 0) {
                happinessBar.setString("Horrible");
                happinessBar.setForeground(Color.black);

            }

            if (mainPet.getHealth() > 75) {
                healthBar.setString("Great");
                healthBar.setForeground(Color.green);
            }
            if (mainPet.getHealth() <= 75) {
                healthBar.setString("Good");
                healthBar.setForeground(Color.magenta);
            }
            if (mainPet.getHealth() <= 50) {
                healthBar.setString("OK");
                healthBar.setForeground(Color.orange);
            }
            if (mainPet.getHealth() <= 25) {
                healthBar.setString("Requires attention");
                healthBar.setForeground(Color.red);
            }
            if (mainPet.getHealth() <= 0) {
                    healthBar.setString("Death");
                    healthBar.setForeground(Color.black);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your pet: " + mainPet.getName() + " has died.");
                p.dispose();
                StartGUI.main(null);
                break;



            }

            if (mainPet.getHunger() > 75) {
                hungerBar.setString("Full");
                hungerBar.setForeground(Color.green);
            }
            if (mainPet.getHunger() <= 75) {
                hungerBar.setString("Great");
                hungerBar.setForeground(Color.magenta);
            }
            if (mainPet.getHunger() <= 50) {
                hungerBar.setString("Hungry");
                hungerBar.setForeground(Color.orange);
            }
            if (mainPet.getHunger() <= 25) {
                hungerBar.setString("Empty");
                hungerBar.setForeground(Color.red);
            }
            if (mainPet.getHunger() <= 0) {
                hungerBar.setString("Starving");
                hungerBar.setForeground(Color.black);
            }


            //death values
            if (mainPet.getHunger() <= 5) {
                mainPet.setHealth(mainPet.getHealth() - 1);
            }
            if (mainPet.getHealth() <= 45) {
                mainPet.setHappiness(mainPet.getHappiness() - 1);
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public static int getFood() {
        return food;
    }

    public static void setFood(int food) {
        PetUI.food = food;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == quitButton) {
            int quit = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to quit?");
            if (quit == 0) {
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                //do nothing, just stay
            }
        } else if (e.getSource() == feedButton) {
            if (getFood() <= 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are out of food.");
            } else if (mainPet.getHunger() > 100) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You do not need food right now.");
            } else {
                mainPet.setHunger(mainPet.getHunger() + 20);
                setFood(getFood() - 1);

            }
        } else if (e.getSource() == healButton) {
            if (getMedpacks() <= 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are out of medpacks.");
            } else if (mainPet.getHealth() > 100) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You do not need a medpack right now.");
            } else {

               if(mainPet.getHealth() + 20 >= 100) {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You do not need a medpack right now.");
               }
                else {
                   setMedpacks(getMedpacks() - 1);
               }
            }

        }
        else if(e.getSource() == save) {
            io.replaceMainPet("");
        }

    }
}
```

### `StartGUI` Class:

```
package vps.main.gui;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import vps.util.io;
import vps.util.io.*;
/**
 * Created by XXX on 3/25/2016.
 */
public class StartGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public static String readPath = "";
    static JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JLabel vpstitle = new JLabel("VPS Alpha 1.2",JLabel.CENTER);
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem newSave = new JMenuItem("New Save");
    JMenuItem openSave = new JMenuItem("Open Save");
    JButton play = new JButton("Play");
    JButton help = new JButton("Help");

    public StartGUI() {
        super("Startup");
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        add(vpstitle);
        add(play);
        add(help);
        play.addActionListener(this);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        fileMenu.add(newSave);
        fileMenu.add(openSave);
        newSave.addActionListener(this);
        openSave.addActionListener(this);
        vpstitle.setFont(new Font ("Segoe Print", Font.BOLD , 72));

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StartGUI s = new StartGUI();
        s.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        s.setSize(720,480);
        s.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        s.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static String getReadPath() {
        return readPath;
    }

    public static void setReadPath(String readPath) {
        StartGUI.readPath = readPath;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == play) {
            try {
                if (readPath.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a save file.\nFile --> Open Save / New Save");

                }
                else {
                    PetUI.main(null);
                }
            }
                catch(NullPointerException n) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You didn't choose a file.");
                }
            }
        else if(e.getSource() == newSave) {
            String saveName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please name this save file:");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Select your new save directory.");
            JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();
            jf.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            jf.showOpenDialog(null);
            readPath = jf.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()+"\\"+ saveName+".bin";
            io.write(readPath);
            io.replaceMainPet(readPath);
        } else if (e.getSource() == openSave) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Press OK to select your previous save file.");
            JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();
            jf.showOpenDialog(null);
            readPath = jf.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            io.replaceMainPet(readPath);
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason for you to call the static method of your class `PetUI.main(null);` to get an instance, instead of directly creating the instance `new PetUI();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your game loop into a thread. It is doing your game logic instead of updating the swing gui which is why you need to split them up. I would also suggest adding a boolean method to `Pet.java` as `isAlive()` so that when your pet dies or when the game is over the thread will die. For example in `PetUI.java`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PetUI p = new PetUI();
    p.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    p.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    p.setSize(640, 480);
    p.setVisible(true);
    Thread game = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            while (true) { // while(mainPet.isAlive())
                happinessBar.setValue((int) Math.round(mainPet.getHappiness()));
                healthBar.setValue((int) Math.round(mainPet.getHealth()));
                hungerBar.setValue((int) Math.round(mainPet.getHunger()));
                mainPet.setHappiness(mainPet.getHappiness() - 0.1);
                mainPet.setHunger(mainPet.getHunger() - 0.5);
                // the rest of your game method
            }
        }
    }
    game.start();
}
```

Comment: It depends and I haven't had much trouble using them together. It shouldn't be an issue with what you are doing.

Comment: Why are you using static variables ?

Comment: Yes. You need to reset everything back to normal.

Comment: `static` makes your elements belong to the class instead of the instance. The only things that need to be `static final` are constants.

Comment: It may make more sense to define your `mainPet` inside `main()` or `Thread game` since you don't seem to be accessing it anywhere else.

Comment: You should make all non-constants values non-static